# Play audio on image click - mobile/tablet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, audio

I can't get my code to play audio files on the click of an image.
I've tried different file types but it doesn't change anything.

This is the code I'm using:

http://jsfiddle.net/adamsears/kZF9T/

```
<a onclick="playSounds()">
<img src="http://us.123rf.com/400wm/400/400/natis76/natis761205/natis76120500079/13695359-speaker-icon.jpg" width="300px" height="300px" id="ImageButton1">
```

```
    var sounds = [



"http://adambencreative.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/test.mp3",
"http://adambencreative.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/test2.mp3",


          ],
oldSounds = [];

var playSounds = function () {
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (sounds.length)),
    thisSound = sounds[index];

    oldSounds.push(thisSound);
    sounds.splice(index, 1);

    if (sounds.length < 1) {
        sounds = oldSounds.splice(0, oldSounds.length);
    }

 $("#element").html("<audio autoplay><source src=\"" + thisSound + "\" type=\"audio\/mp3\"><\/audio>");
 }
```

Does anyone know how I can get it to work on mobile/tablet too?

Comment: I simply added `$('audio')[0].play();` after adding the `<audio>` element to the page, and it played the sound. Probably some problem with the autoplay feature.

Comment: Sorry, where did you add that code? - If you could copy the exact extract of code you edited that would be great! Or make another jsfiddle using my code, that would be even better! :) @bvx89

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/kZF9T/2/

Comment: No worries, figured it out, thanks a lot!

Comment: You should probably write down what you did to fix it for others to see.